# LINQ - Group by and Sum over joined tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, aggregation

I am trying to replicate a SQL query, using 2 joins, and then group by and sum.

For this example, i have used the Nortwind database, where i am trying to show for each product, which customers have purchased, and how many they have purchased.

The SQL is as follows

```
select p.productid,p.ProductName, c.companyname, 
        c.CustomerID,
        sum(od.quantity) as qty_ord
from products as p
inner join [Order Details] as od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID
inner join orders as o on od.OrderID=o.OrderID
inner join customers as c on o.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
where p.productid=1     --  Not in query just for debugging/checking linq
group by p.ProductID,p.ProductName,c.customerid, c.companyname
```

and i have used the following c#

```
var productsalesbycust =
                (
                from p in context.Products join
                od in context.Order_Details on p.ProductID equals od.ProductID join
                o in context.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID join
                c in context.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                where p.ProductID==1        //  To be removed
                group new {p,c,od} by new
                {
                    p.ProductName,
                    c.CompanyName,
                    c.CustomerID,
                    od.Quantity
                } into g
                select new
                {
                    g.Key.ProductName,
                    g.Key.CustomerID,
                    g.Key.CompanyName, 
                    t= g.Sum(x=>x.od.Quantity)
                }
                );
```

This is not giving me quite what i want, the numbers are correct, but the grouping is not working.

[image]

Comment: Try following : group new {p.ProductName,c.CompanyName,c.CustomerID} by new

Comment: I changed to `group new {p.ProductName,c.CompanyName} by new` and it worked, many thanks.  I had the `od.Quantity` in the group by too, which should have alerted me to that :)

Comment: You only need `group od.Quantity by new { p.ProductName, c.CompanyName, c.CustomerID } into g`  then select the values in the key and do `g.Sum()`